# What is the information called below a data table?

Tags: word-choice

I can't think very well these days, and I can't figure this out.

I have a table I'm using for a web page. I have some footer information, and text from the superscript in the table, data sources, notes, etc. It's not a simple caption, but actually explanations of the data. I'm either going to have it like an expanding link, or have a modal popup come up and give that info.

My question is: what should that link be called? What is the grouping of information regarding the data in a table?

thanks.

Comment: Are they “table notes”?

Comment: Sounds like footnotes.

Comment: I don't think table notes fits. and footnotes seem to be more on the bottom of the page, not really for a table or for a word-signal for a popup.